# Real-Time приложение (Spring Boot + Rest API + Hibernate + Angular)

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, angular

Покупатель интернет-магазина находится на странице товара. Сотрудник интернет-магазина обновил информацию о товаре на "нет в наличии". В этот же момент, без вмешательства покупателя, информация на странице, о наличии товара, обновляется.

Какую технологию нужно использовать чтобы информация из БД подгружалась в режиме real-time?

Comment: [сокеты](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets)?

Comment: @overthesanity да, это оно) спасибо)